# help for writing to files in java

Tags: java, file-io

Hi
I have created a class named 'Human' that each object of this class has a name and a type which can be student or instructor. I have created another class main which creates object of Human and assign type and name to the objects and add that objects into a linkedList. Now I want to write this linkedList into a file,but i dont know how. i must write both objects and their type into that linkedList. i have created following as the Main class but I have problem in the writing file parts. would you please guide me?

```
public class Testing {

    public static LinkedList<Human> link =new LinkedList<Human>();
    static FileOutputStream fop;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        File f=new File("textfile1.txt");
        try {
            fop=new FileOutputStream(f);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Human hm = new Human();
        Human hum = new Human();
        hm.setName("Anna");
        hm.setType("Student");
        hum.setName("Elvis");
        hum.setType("Instructor");
        link.add(hm);
        link.add(hum);
        for (Human h : link) {
            fop.write(h.getType());
            fop.write(h);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: it depends on what you want written to the file. Do you want the values, the serlialised object, an xml representation?

Comment: In readable form. or in binary form?

Answer (score 2):

Look at [java.io.PrintStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)

```
PrintStream p = new PrintStream(fop);
for (Human h : link) {
  p.println(h.getType());
  p.println(h);
}
p.close();
```

Assuming you have implemented a [toString](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method for Human.

Answer (score 1):

An easy and working solution for your problem would be creating a simple "CSV" file, this would be a readable representation of your `Human` objects and look like:

```
Anna;Student
Elvis;Instructor
```

You can achieve this with doing:

```
for (Human h : link) {
  String line = h.toString() + ";" + h.getType() + "\n";
  fop.write(line.getBytes());
}
```

Comment: does it a good way if I want to add another method in the Test class to read the 'textfile' _which i have created with the above code_ ino a linkedList?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the Objects to a file, you need to use serialization. Make the Human object to implement `Serializable` interface and then refer [how to write the object to an output stream using serialization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm).